# How to change column datatype from character to numeric in PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: postgresql

I am using following query:

```
ALTER TABLE presales ALTER COLUMN code TYPE numeric(10,0);
```

to change the datatype of a column from `character(20)` to `numeric(10,0)` but I am getting the error:

> column "code" cannot be cast to type numeric

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You can try using [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html):

> The optional `USING` clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

So this might work (depending on your data):

```
alter table presales alter column code type numeric(10,0) using code::numeric;
-- Or if you prefer standard casting...
alter table presales alter column code type numeric(10,0) using cast(code as numeric);
```

This will fail if you have anything in `code` that cannot be cast to numeric; if the USING fails, you'll have to clean up the non-numeric data by hand before changing the column type.

Comment: this column is used as a foreign key in another table, i guess i will have to change the datatype of that too?

Comment: @user728630: You'll have to drop the FK, change both columns, and then add the FK back. You do have a test database to play with and a backup of the production database, right?

Comment: i deleted the foreign key constraint , changed the datatype but after that unable to add the FK. Getting the following error

ERROR:  insert or update on table "invoices" violates foreign key constraint "invoice_presale_fk"

DETAIL:  Key (sale,cpf_cnpj)=(4,05943560000101) is not present in table "presales".

Comment: @user728630: Is the leading zero on `cpf_cnpj` a problem? Sorry, I don't have enough context to know what's wrong.

Comment: What does the `code::numeric` represent?  I can't find any more documentation on the USING syntax or what you could use for that parameter.

Comment: @funwhilelost That's a [type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). The linked ALTER TABLE docs cover what you can use with USING.

Comment: @muistooshort I see from the docs it's actually an expression.  That makes more sense.  The type cast caught me off guard.  I ended up with `TYPE varchar(255) USING (substring(formertextcolumn from 1 for 255))`

Answer (score 8):

If your `VARCHAR` column contains empty strings (which are *not* the same as `NULL` for PostgreSQL as you might recall) you will have to use something in the line of the following to set a default:

```
ALTER TABLE presales ALTER COLUMN code TYPE NUMERIC(10,0)
            USING COALESCE(NULLIF(code, '')::NUMERIC, 0);
```

(found with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18950952/1033075))

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Add new column with integer or numeric as per your requirement

Step 2: Populate data from varchar column to numeric column

Step 3: drop varchar column

Step 4: change new numeric column name as per old varchar column