# Postgres Alter table to convert column type from char to bigint

Tags: postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to change column datatype from character to numeric in postgresql 8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683359/how-to-change-column-datatype-from-character-to-numeric-in-postgresql-8-4)

If I have a field of type varchar (and all the values are null or string representations of numbers) how do I use alter table to convert this column type to bigint?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

To convert simply by parsing the string (casting):

```
alter table the_table alter column the_column type bigint using the_column::bigint
```

In fact, you can use any expression in terms of `the_column` instead of `the_column::bigint` to customise the conversion.

Note this will rewrite the table, locking out even readers until it's done.

Comment: Great!  This plainly renders my answer wrong. so I've deleted it.  And learnt something new.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a temporary column of type `bigint`, and then execute SQL like

```
UPDATE my_table SET bigint_column=varchar_column::bigint;
```

Then drop your varchar_column and rename bigint_column.  This is kinda roundabout, but will not require a custom cast in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

### How to convert a string column type to numeric or bigint in postgresql

Design your own custom cast from string to bigint.  Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_to_bigint(v_input text)
RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
DECLARE v_bigint_value BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        v_bigint_value := v_input::BIGINT;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Invalid bigint value: "%".  Returning something else.', v_input;
        RETURN 0;
    END;
RETURN v_bigint_value;
END;
```

Then create a new table `fixed_table_with_bigint` with the same parameters as the old table except change the string column into the bigint column.

Then insert all the rows from the previous table (using the custom cast `convert_to_integer` ) into the new table:

```
insert into fixed_table_with_bigint
select mycolumn1, 
       convert_to_bigint(your_string_bigint_column),
       mycolumn3
    from incorrect_table
```

You may have to modify `convert_to_bigint` in order to handle strings which are not numbers, blankstrings, nulls, control characters and other Weirdness.

Then delete the first table and rename the 2nd table as the first table.