# rake db:migrate returns "Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds.."

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migrate, mysql2

I can't understand what's wrong with my migration syntax, please help.
I ran rake db:migrate, database in MySql2

error:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
>       that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'USING CAST(number AS integer) DEFAULT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `seats` CHANGE 
>       `number` `number` integer USING CAST(number AS integer) DEFAULT NULL

below it the syntax:

```
class ChangeNumberTypeInSeats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :seats, :number, 'integer USING CAST(number AS integer)'
  end
end
```

My guess is that because my partner uses PostgreSQL locally, but pushed the code anyway to out Git. Please help.

Comment: @Monica_Agustin May you add your `database.yml` to question?

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of `change_column`:

```
'integer USING CAST(number AS integer)'
```

is a postgres way to convert column from one type to another (in this case to integer) ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7683398/580346)).

If you want to use database-specific code in migrations, you need to agree what DB you use and do it consistently across the team. Postgres-specific code will not run on Mysql and vice-versa.

It's generally a good idea to have the same DB across the team, and the same one as on production (to keep [dev-prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity)).